# can I use cygwin with bash script to update Android manifest on commit?

Tags: android, svn, cygwin, commit, pre-commit

I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579697/android-how-to-make-the-versioncode-update-automatically-with-every-build that contains the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                             

MANIFEST="AndroidManifest.xml"                                                  

if [ -f $MANIFEST ]                                                             
then                                                                            
    LINE=$(grep -o ${MANIFEST} -e 'android:versionCode="[0-9]*"');              
    declare -a LINE;                                                            
    LINE=(`echo $LINE | tr "\"" " "`);                                          
    VERSION=(${LINE[1]});                                                       
    INCREMENTED=$(($VERSION+1))                                                 
    sed "s/android:versionCode=\"[0-9]*\"/android:versionCode=\"${INCREMENTED}\"/" $MANIFEST > $MANIFEST.tmp && mv $MANIFEST.tmp $MANIFEST
    git add $MANIFEST                                                           
    echo "Updated android:versionCode to ${INCREMENTED} in ${MANIFEST}";        
fi
```

I'm using a TortoiseSVN with a windows SVN server however (VisualSVN) so I'm wondering if this could be put into a cygwin command somehow so that the pre-commit hooks in svn can run this?  I've not used cygwin much, but am looking for a way to have my version name update every time a commit is built.

Edit: actually it looks like you can use a tool call FARThttp://fart-it.sourceforge.net/ to find and replace text, so i may be able to write a batch script in the SVN pre-commit to find and replace the text.

Edit #2: FART would be more complicated, I'm going to try using the first script, but replace "git add" with "svn add" and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Maven (which [supports Android development](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/)) with [buildnumber plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/).

It let's you create build numbers via an SCM, via a sequential build number, or via a timestamp. See [usage page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the same post you mentioned, I posted a different solution, because SVN boldly recommends not changing the commit content with a pre-commit hook , you can make it all go corrupt! 
Your manifest can keep the same versionCode forever in svn, instead you should change /bin/AndroidManifest.xml , that is the one which will be packaged in the .apk file